# 2d grid vision(eye sensor) for a neural network bot?

Tags: c++, 2d, tiles, geometry, grid

I have a 2d grid and neural network bots living above it. What is a good way to give them vision of tiles in front of them?

Below I describe my idea that I don't know how to efficiently(or inefficiently) implement.

Bots can see other bots like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtlZsOlx1yk) and it's already slowed my simulation, because I'm not so smart I guess and there is no code from this video available. I mean I've implemented it as good as I could and it doesn't bother itself with tiles, only with other bots. But due to the large amount of tiles to see in front of them and the fact that my bots can travel above them, I've decided to make a separate eye sensor just for tiles(soil, plants). No need to see other bots using this sensor.

My first idea was to get a cone vision, and I can get tiles inside this cone(triangle for simplicity) using triangle rasterization. BUT then I need to put all found tiles into 1D(or 2D doesn't matter) array that will make sense for my bots. And for that it must always be of the same size. And tile that is CCW to vision cone start and CW to another tile must always be between 1D array start and CW tile. And if tile is farther away from another tile inside cone(concentric circles), it must always be further away in 1D array.

But now I think it's too difficult and computationally expensive.

Shape of the vision cone is constant but number of tiles that fit with current rotation can differ. On this picture I check distance to the tile center and that center is inside using brute force approach, but I think during triangle rasterization it will differ as well.

On the picture you can see bot and his vision cone and 1D array I imagined. Null means that on this concentric arc could have been more tiles but in this rotation they are not inside. I don't know how to calculate number of tiles on each level. I think on the first always can fit only 1 tile and it's 0. On the second can be 1 or 2, now it's two(1,2). On third it can be 2(maybe more, I don't know how to calculate) tiles but now it's only one, number 3. etc.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear to me: in your eye vision (cone detection) does the fact that you're working with neural net matters? Or you just want to know how you could detect 'other bots' in a cone in the front of the bot?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I need to represent sensory info for my neural network and because of that I need constant size input. And position of a tile  inside 1D input vector must be independent of rotation. My bots don't live inside grid, I have a working eye sensor for objects above the grid.(10 max inside visibility circle) But now I need eye sensor just for tiles. On the left side of the picture you can see that depending on the rotation different number of tiles can be visible + order of tile reading depends on rotation as well.

Comment: So you need a way to 'convert' the tile locations that are in the cone in the front of the bot to a 1d array, with the first 1d index representing a tile just in front of the bot, and the last array index being further away in the cone, something like that?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I didn't want to(maybe can't) provide angle, distance and color in implicit way. I wanted to make network base its decisions on just array of colors and the order inside array will incode angle(angle from vision conus start) and distance.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Yes! That's what I need. How to traverse(or compute order) triangle/conus from center in concentric arcs. Using triangle rasterization I can traverse all tiles inside triangle but order will be different for almost every rotation. And it must be not very slow. Right now I test everything for 300 bots.

Comment: This should make your question clearer :)

Comment: Actually order inside 1D array doesn't matter, it just must be consistent for every rotation.

Comment: This is what I'm doing for now.. http://i.imgur.com/DxjlJeR.jpg Using Bresenham's line algorithm I'm able to restore order of tiles from center to line end and I''m casting two lines.